# how to assign default value to the radio button in knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I want to assign some values as a default value to the radio button When page loads
this is my code

```
 <input type="radio" name="year-end-method" 
    id="calendar-radio" 
    data-bind="checked: Selectedgroup.Yearendtype" value="Calendar">
```

This does not works for me

```
 $('input:radio[name="year-end-method"]    
 [value="RealTime"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: just assign `true` to your observable binding in viewModel like `Yearendtype(true)`. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set value to true on load.

```
Yearendtype = ko.observable(true)
```

From documentation

> For radio buttons, KO will set the element to be checked if and only
>   if the parameter value equals the radio button node’s value attribute.

For more details take a look [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html)

Comment: Thankx it helped a lot..Yearendtype = ko.observable("RealTime").I assigned the value directly It works fine

Comment: yes you should be doing like that value/checkedValue and checked binding should be in sync . cheers